# What causes IdentifierGenerationException when trying to cascade a OneToOne join in JPA and how to fix it?

Tags: jpa

I want to OneToOne join an optional entity to another and cascade all. They share the same ID: A measure has an ID. Because of legacy applications I couldn't extend this table. I built another table ONV which has a primary key which is a foreign key for the measure ID.

Excerpt from measure entity

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "MES001_ID", columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier")
private UUID id;

// This is my problem
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "measure", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues overwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues;

// This works as expected
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "measure", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<MeasureAccruals> measureAccruals;
```

Excerpt from OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues entity

```
@Id
private UUID measureId;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name = "ONV001_MES001_ID")
private Measure measure;
```

I trigger the creation of the child entity and use this method:

```
public void createOverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValue() {
    if (selectedMeasure != null
        && selectedMeasure.getOverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues() == null) {
        OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues tempONV = new OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues();
        selectedMeasure.setOverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues(tempONV);
        tempONV.setMeasure(selectedMeasure);
    }
}
```

The parent (measure) is later saved by `entityManager.merge`

Upon creation of the child I get this error `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [...OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues.measure]`

The child is only created upon the method shown. I noticed that it's constructor is called twice - once upon `createOverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValue` and once upon the merge operation. In a `@PrePersist` method I can see that the measure is null at that moment despite I correctly set it before and can output it's id.

I tried many combinations - with this code I can read, update and delete children. I could as well create children in one combination but this only worked on already existing measures. If I create a new measure that didn't already get an ID by the database, it never worked. I showed the relation to a measureAccruals in the code above - this works as expected and I would like to save my measure cascading all children, not by persisting different elementy manually.

**Edit**
For clarification: The following code allows me everything but the creation of a OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues for a new Measure. For MeasureAccessRights it's working. The differences are: MeasureAccessRights has a composite key, @IdClass and is a OneToMany relation.

I am using hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2-Final.

```java
public class Measure implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "MES001_ID", columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier")
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "measure", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<MeasureAccessRights> measureAccessRights;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "measure", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues overwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues;

    ...
}

@Entity
@IdClass(MeasureAccessRightsKey.class)
public class MeasureAccessRights implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "MAR001_MES001_ID")
    private UUID mar001;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "MAR001_MES001_ID", referencedColumnName = "MES001_ID", columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Measure measure;

    ...
}

@Entity
public class OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ONV001_MES001_ID")
    private UUID measureId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ONV001_MES001_ID", referencedColumnName = "MES001_ID", columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Measure measure;

    ...
}

//Method to create OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValue
public void createOverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValue() {
    if (selectedMeasure != null
        && selectedMeasure.getOverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues() == null) {
        OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues tempONV = new OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues();
        tempONV.setMeasure(selectedMeasure);
        selectedMeasure.setOverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues(tempONV);
    }
}
```

When invoking the create method on a not yet saved Measure entity I get this exception: `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()`

Comment: You mean in the `@JoinColumn`? In this case no, it's our convention: The table's field refers to MES001_ID so it's labeled like this.

Comment: I think I don't get it. I could add a `, referencedColumnName = "MES001_ID"` to the child's `@JoinColumn` or what do you mean?

Comment: You mean like this: `@JoinColumn(name = "MES001_ID")`?
In this case I get `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet` caused by `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'MES001_ID'`.

Comment: @Mar-Z JoinColumn name defines the FK column in this table, so doesn't need to match the column it references. What is there is the same as @JoinColumn(name = "ONV001_MES001_ID", referencedColumnName  = "MES001_ID"). MapsId tells JPA this column should be used for measureId and to use the relationship to set the value.

Comment: Error here is that hibernate says the OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues.measure reference is null - Are you sure it is complaining about the code you posted exactly?  How are you persisting this child OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues instance, and was there one already mapped to this Measure entity at some point before?

Comment: @Chris I put a `Thread.dumpStack()` in the constructor. When the child is instantiated the second time the last element in the stack of my code is the line where `entityManager.merge` is called. After that it's a lot of hibernate and java.base lines before it shows `OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues.<init>(OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues.java:68)`

Comment: Oh and I forgot to answer this: The child is / shall be persisted via cascade of the parent entity. There was a mapping 'at some point before' but when I restart my server the database table is completly empty. If I insert a row manually, it is correctly read and can be updated and deleted.

Comment: I'm at a loss, as if the OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues.measure just isn't being set when merge is called on the Parent Measure instance, it'd be a bug in Hibernate.  Are there any other properties in OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues that might also be being left out when it is merged/persisted? Are you using Lombok to generate or your own hashcode/equals methods? Are there any other calls to OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues.setMeasure going on?

Comment: There's only the 'value' field which is set upon update. HashCode and Equals depend on both fields (measure and value). The logging shows that the constructor and setMeasure method of OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues are called as expected. Upon merge (only) the constructor is called again. The field measureId holds a UUID on @PrePersist but measure is NULL. The the error is thrown.

Comment: I amended/clarified my question beginning from 'Edit'.

Comment: With your latest changes, you must assign the ID property yourself - you made the reference mapping read only, so it doesn't control the FK/ID and isn't liked to the ID property at all. You've now shown MeasureAccruals/MeasureAccessRights, and while it is a composite PK, you are also manually getting the UUID and assigning it to the mar001 ID property as you have not marked the relationship as MapsId. If MapsId isn't working anywhere for you, try a later hibernate version. You can also mark the relationship as the ID directly, it doesn't require a basic mapping since JPA 2.1

Comment: I think you have something else going on though, as I don't see how the UUID property is set but the measure relationship is null - the UUID can only be set from the relationship, and only after it gets assigned into the measure instance. You might want to add breakpoints in your entities and see where things might be getting modified more actively - or some event listener registered on Measure is doing it

Comment: Please check your entity classes. Need to be annotated as such and need a no-args constructor and getters and setters for all fields.

Comment: In between I've had another try: Instead of OneToOne I modeled the `OverwriteNewbuildingAllocationValues` entity as a List with `@OneToMany`. I accordingly added a getter and setter for the first element of the list and changed th create and delete method to hold a list with 0 or 1 entries. Without further modifications it is now working as expected - despite being an unsafe workaround. I guess this migth origin in the old hibernate version?